# why the address of the global variable has changed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I declare a personkey in the .h file in the person class，Print personkey's address in Person's singleton method

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static const void*  personKey = &personKey;

@interface Person : NSObject

+(instancetype)sharedPerson;

@end

#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

static Person *_person;

+ (instancetype)sharedPerson
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _person = [[self alloc] init];
        printf("personkey111 = %p\n",personKey);
    });
    return _person;
}

@end
```

but when I print it in another class,the adress has changed.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    Person *p = [Person sharedPerson];
    printf("personKey222 = %p,",personKey);
}
```

here is my output

```
personkey111 = 0x10c70c0e8
personKey222 = 0x10c70c0e0,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement `static const void*  personKey = &personKey;` in .h file declare a independent const pointer with its memory position as value. When import the .h file, the .h file just copy the content of the preceded file. It means you have two independent `personKey` pointer contains their own locations.When you state `static const void*  personKey = "&personKey";`, the two pointers hold the location of string `"&personKey"`, which is in the static zone.

Comment: thankyou,I think I understand,one of my colleagues also explain like this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code like this,

```
static const void*  personKey = "&personKey";
```

here is my output

```
personkey111 = 0x109ce54c0
personKey222 = 0x109ce54c0,
```

But I still don‘t know why my first way didn't work